# Jarowinkler as a loadable extension to SQLite

Tags: sqlite, levenshtein-distance, jaro-winkler

I was wondering if anyone has implemented the Jarowinkler function as a loadable extension to SQLite.

I am looking for an equivalent to the " SQLite-Levenshtein". A great implementation of the levenstehein distance as an SQLite loadable extenstion by Mateusz Adamowski

https://github.com/mateusza/SQLite-Levenshtein

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am also looking for a similarity function in SQLite. levenshtein-distance, sorenson,jaccard and jaro_winkler. as a windows dll

Comment: Users landing on this question may find the following repo interesting: https://github.com/nalgeon/sqlean.